# Can only write one word on chat batch file

Tags: batch-file, chat, goto

The code below is the part of my program. My problem is that when i enter my message it works perfectly if its 1 word. but if it is more it says goto was expected. the Q and R options are needed to refresh the chat and pop up a quit prompt.

```
set /p M=Enter Your Message:
if %M%==Q goto B
if %M%==q goto B
if %M%==R goto A
if %M%==r goto A
echo %U%: %M% >>%S%.txt
```

What should i do?

ps. this is my first quistion on here sorry if formating is wrong)

Answer (score 1):

If the input has more than one word, the parser will see, after variable replacement

```
if this is a test==Q goto B
```

which is an invalid command.

Simplest solution is to use quotes

```
if "%M%"=="Q" goto B
....
```

will be interpreted as

```
if "this is a test"=="Q" goto B
```

**edited** to adapt to comments

This is a skeleton of a chat script with "auto update" in the terms indicated in the comments.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Configuration
    set "chatFile=c:\temp\chat.txt"
    set "lastSize=-1"

:selectOption
    rem Update screen
    call :refresh 

    rem retrieve user selection
    >nul choice /c rqw /n /t 3 /d r /m ""

    rem Check what has been selected
    if errorlevel 3 call :write & goto :selectOption
    if errorlevel 2 goto :quit

    rem Select another option
    goto :selectOption


:refresh [bForceRefresh]
    rem Check if refresh is being forced
    if not "%~1"=="" set "lastSize=-1"

    rem Ensure we have a file
    if not exist "%chatFile%" >"%chatFile%" echo(

    rem Check if we can skip the refresh. 
    rem If file has no changed its size there are no changes in content
    for %%a in ("%chatFile%") do if %%~za leq %lastSize% ( 
        goto :skipRefresh 
    ) else ( 
        set "lastSize=%%~za" 
    )

    rem Paint the screen
    cls
    type "%chatFile%"

    rem Show the options
    echo(
    <nul set /p ".=[R]efresh [Q]uit [W]rite ?"
:skipRefresh
    goto :eof


:write
    setlocal
    rem Ask message
    echo(
    echo(
    set "message="
    set /p "message=What do you want to say? >"

    rem If there is a message, write to output file, 
    rem else force screen refresh to remove the message question
    if defined message (
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >>"%chatFile%" echo(%time% :[ %username% ]: !message!
        endlocal
    ) else (
        call :refresh forceRefresh
    )
    endlocal 
    goto :eof

:quit
    cls
    exit /b
```

Comment: thanks a lot....i have 1 more question. Is there any way to make this refresh well still letting you to type your message?

Comment: :A
cls
Echo Server: %S%
Echo Press Q to Quit Or Press R to refresh chat log.
echo ---------------------------------------------------------
type %S%.txt
echo ---------------------------------------------------------
set /p M=Enter Your Message:
if "%M%"=="Q" goto B
if "%M%"=="q" goto B
if "%M%"=="R" goto A
if "%M%"=="r" goto A
echo %U%: %M% >>%S%.txt
goto A

Comment: it got messed...up there...dont know how to fix it

Comment: @hunterguimont, change your `set /p` with a `choice` command and include an option to type the message. `choice` allows to include a timeout. If it is reached, execute the autorefresh.

Comment: but that will make it so if they are in the middle of writing a message they will have to restart.

Comment: @hunterguimont, no, the idea is to select what to do with a `choice` command. If the user does not select anything, or if he selects refresh, then refresh. If the user selects write, then `set /p` is used. You can not skip the input, so, while writting the process will be stopped, but only when the user selects to write.

Comment: @hunterguimont, answer updated. I've included a basic skeleton using a mixed `choice - set /p`. Adapt as needed

Comment: how can a add an option to your >nul choice /c rqw /n /t 3 /d r /m "" thing

Comment: @hunterguimont, the rqw is the list of options. The first one will set error level 1, the second errorlevel 2, ... See choice /?

Comment: ok thx i already got it tho. btw i have a problem. if somebody wants to delete the server they press d... it takes them to :Sercurity 
If /I "%Admin%"=="%U%" goto :delete

Echo YOU ARE NOT ADMIN!
pause>nul
Goto :selectOption

Comment: And it goes black screen if not admin